# Use Ellipse with origin in the center WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, ellipse

I have a program that I can drag, rotate and resize a `System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse` in a `Canvas` panel.

To resize and drag the ellipse inside the canvas and always keep it center I need to correct every time its origin, because the ellipse has it origin in the top left corner.

Have a  way to make the origin in the `Ellipse` on center by default?

Drag:

```
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, newX - (ellipse.Height / 2));
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, newY - (ellipse.Width / 2));
```

Resize:

```
ellipse.Height = newHeight;
ellipse.Width = newWidth;
```

Rotate:

```
ellipse.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(angle,(ellipse.Width/2),(ellipse.Height/2));
```

Comment: You are drawing ellipse using drawingContext or it's through WPF inbuilt controls?

Comment: @RohitVats with inbuilt controls, from Windows.System.Shapes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the width and height are fixed, the simplest solution would be to set the Ellipse's `RenderTransform` to a `TranslateTransform` with `X` and `Y` set to negative offsets equal to half the ellipse's width and height, respectively:

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
  <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="-50" Y="-50" />
  </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

Note that a caveat of using `RenderTransform` is that the transform is not applied to layout (and you cannot use a `TranslateTransform` for the `LayoutTransform`).  That shouldn't be an issue with a `Canvas` because of how it handles layout, though it might be problematic with other panels.

Comment: Not worked, when I drag the ellipse its still in the top left corner the origin.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that in your original post you are already setting the `RenderTransform` to a `RotateTransform`.  Are you overwriting the `TranslateTransform`?  If you want to set both, you'll need to use a `TransformGroup`.

Comment: Also, you _might_ need to set `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` in order to rotate around the center of the ellipse.

Comment: Isn't there a way to solve this more generally using a data binding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Margin property.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" 
                     Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="150" 
                     Width="50" Height="50" 
                     Margin="-25,-25" 
                     Stroke="Red"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```